# Insert multiple SObject data in Salesforce as single transaction using REST calls

Tags: rest-api, sobject, query, rest, translation

I am using following soObject call to insert new row in the Account table at Salesforce server :

```
curl -H "Authorization:OAuth use your session_id" -H "Content-Type: application/json" -d @Test.json "https://ap1.salesforce.com/services/data/v20.0/sobjects/Account/
```

Now I need to insert an Account, Contacts and Address (in Address__c) as a single transaction means If insertion to any of the Account, Contact or Address fails, all three insertion should roll back.

How can I achieve this ?

Comment: see this link http://th3silverlining.com/2009/06/15/salesforce-savepoints/ , http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/questions/9905/is-manual-database-setsavepoint-and-rollback-needed-on-trigger-exception

Comment: @nagarjuna given link is talking about apex code, While I am inserting data in salesforce from an external system using sobjects.

Comment: a custom apex rest service that accepts a json POST payload of all the objects you need to insert is the way to go

Comment: see also @sfdcfox answer here - http://salesforce.stackexchange.com/a/46950/2602

Answer (score 7):

If you want all that to be in 1 single transaction and 1 callout, you might need to write APEX REST Webservice that will get the all the data in a single call and store it as account, contact and any other object.

In this particular scenario let's assume your JSON looks something like this:

```
{
    "account" : {
        "name" : "test account name",
        "contact" : {
            "firstname" : "John",
            "lastname" : "Smith",
            "address" : {
                "street" : "Flinders St",
                "city" : "Melbourne",
                "state" : "VIC",
                "country" : "Australia",
                "postcode" : "3000"
            }
        }
    }
}
```

If that's the case then I recommend you write your webservice like this:

```
@RestResource(urlMapping='/account/*')
global with sharing class YourWebServiceName
{
    global class GenericResponse
    {
        public Boolean success;
        public String errorMessage;
        public String result;

        public GenericResponse(Boolean s, String e)
        {
            if (s == true)
            {
                this.errorMessage = '';
                this.result = e;
            }
            else
            {
                this.errorMessage = e;
                this.result = '';
            }

            this.success = s;
        }
    }

    global class CustomAccount
    {
        public String name;
        public CustomContact contact;
    }

    global class CustomContact
    {
        public String firstname;
        public String lastname;
        public CustomAddress address;
    }

    global class CustomAddress
    {
        public String street;
        public String city;
        public String state;
        public String country;
        public String postcode;
    }



    @HttpPost
    global static GenericResponse createNewAccount(CustomAccount account)
    {
        // do your ifs and elses and check whether the JSON structure is right

        Savepoint savePoint = Database.setSavepoint();

        try
        {
            Account accountRecord = new Account ();
            accountRecord.Name = account.name;
            insert accountRecord;

            Contact contactRecord = new Contact ();
            contactRecord.AccountId = accountRecord.Id;
            contactRecord.FirstName = account.contact.firstname;
            contactRecord.LastName = account.contact.lastname;
            insert contactRecord;

            // I believe it's a custom object and it's related to the contact
            Address__c addressRecord = new Address__c ();
            addressRecord.Contact__c = contactRecord.Id
            addressRecord.Street__c = account.contact.address.street;
            // and so forth
            insert addressRecord;

            return new GenericResponse(true, 'Success');
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            Database.rollback(savePoint);
            return new GenericResponse(false, 'Error occured creating the records - ' + e.getMessage());
        }
    }
}
```

And finally you can call this method by doing a POST request to `https://CSX.salesforce.com/services/apexrest/account` where `CSX` is your org name.

> Don't forget to authenticate first and get the session id / access
>   token and specify it in the header of your http request :)